# Does killing a process helps avoids spyware

Tags: spyware, adware

I'm downloading something from mediafire which really has many sponsor sites that are not good:
ad.xtendmedia.com and mdinfo.com. And possibly the cause of some spyware and adware in my system.
Does killing the whole process of firefox and not closing those pop-up windows(ad sites) helps avoid the effects of those bad sites.

Comment: killing processes is a great way to avoid spyware.  i've noticed that if i kill *explorer.exe* and all *svchost* processes, my computer shuts down and i don't get any spyware.  :)  *(this comment is a joke.  don't kill your explorer/svchost processes unless you know what you're doing.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Probably not.

Basically if it's already downloaded and running, forcing the process to quit will most likely **not** help in any way.

As a site note I have found no malicious scripts on Mediafire.

Comment: yes, but its the pop-ups in that site worries me. 
Maybe the firefox add-ons that I'm using weakens the built-in pop-up blocker. That's why I see many pop-ups while I click on that download button.